# Angular5 - two way data binding with locale date / number format

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a two way data binding on **input**  using locale format for number or Date. See code bellow:

```
<input type="date" [ngModel]="user.date_created | date:'shortDate' " (ngModelChange)="user.date_created=$event" name="date_created"                                                 />
```

app.module.ts also includes custom locale ('de')

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import locale_de from '@angular/common/locales/de';

registerLocaleData(locale_de);
```

and included also in providers:

```
providers: [{
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: 'de'
  }
],
```

What I am able to do, is to get pretty formatted Date in input. User sees [ 20. 12. 2017 ] which is superb. However, if user changes the input to other date (manually), value on model is changed from ISO format to locale string:

model from API, before change in input element:

```
user.date_created: '2017-12-20T12:03:00'
```

model after change in input element:

```
user.date_created: '23. 12. 2017'
```

Property date_created is typeof Date on model in .ts. Basically, I have the same problem with decimals also.

I tried custom formatter directive by [Tomas Trajan](https://blog.ngconsultant.io/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2-ec792082976) which does exactly what I need, except that locale is hardcoded.

Is there any recommended way how to set up two way data binding using locale format or how to inject current locale into Formatter Directive?

Thanks for any advice.